# No sound from speakers and also earphones

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard, elementary

[information regarding sound cards present in my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF9Sw.png)

There is no sound coming from earphones ans also speakers, I am using elementary os loki which is based on ubuntu. More information regarding can be found in this link.

[Alsa information script](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=3317b39bdf17f03c55fbe7d7acd639956945ec98)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my English is not good , hope you understand

Firstly you plug your headphones and speaker on monitor or pc?

This is the solve solution

Try turning the volume up

if it's not work

Look pc sound cable is steady in  motherboard sounds pin

If it's still not work

Try re plug you headphones or speaker and reboot your system

I hope this can help you